# wait for input after command line prompt in javascript

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, prompt

I am trying to set a local variable with user input using prompt. I am using javascript and running it with node in the command line. I have installed the prompt module and I am using it in the method. The problem that I have is that the execution of statements after prompt.get() do not wait until user input is entered. The rest of the method I am writing relies on the option variable. I would like to set option before executing anything after prompt.get(). Here is the code

```js
function main_loop(){
  var prompt = require('prompt');
  console.log("OPTIONS");
  console.log("=========");
  console.log("1. Use a potion");
  console.log("2. Go to the next room");
  console.log("3. Exclaim ' Die you wizard!!!'");
  console.log("4. Exit game");
  var option;
  prompt.get(['option'], function(err, result){
    option = result.option;
    console.log("option is: " + option);
  });
  console.log(option);

}
main_loop();
```

Here is the output. I run it through node and enter 1.

> Blockquote

```
OPTIONS
=========
1. Use a potion
2. Go to the next room
3. Exclaim ' Die you wizard!!!'
4. Exit game
prompt: option:  undefined
1
option is: 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

`prompt.get()` is an **asynchronous** function. This means, it executes the get function an when it's done it executes the *anonymous callback function* (which sets the option to result.option), and simultaniously it jumps to the next statement, which is `console.log(option)`.

This means the `console.log(option)` get's executed before the anonymous callback function has the chance to set the option to `result.option`.

Answer (score -1):

You could declare a variable and store the user input in it. Then use an if-statement to check if the variable is empty or not. If it is not empty (the user typed something) you could start outputting the things in the order you like.